# URL Rewrite error in PHP (404 error)

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use URL Rewrite for a webpage. I have the following code in functions.php

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
$aVars[] = "play";
return $aVars;
}

// hook add_query_vars function into query_vars
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');


function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
$aNewRules = array('^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$([^/]*)/([^/]*)/&play=$matches[1]');
$aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
return $aRules;
}

// hook add_rewrite_rules function into rewrite_rules_array
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

And this code in single.php, where I include a single-{custom}.php upon the parameter I receive:

```
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);

$parametro = $query['play'];

if ($parametro == 'jugar')
{
    include( get_template_directory() . '/single-play.php');
}
else if ($parametro == 'full')
{
    include( get_template_directory() . '/single-full.php');
}
```

With that code I want to rewrite the URLS, instead of use by example `../juegos/ddtank/?play=full` I want to use `../juegos/ddtank/full/`

Also for `.../juegos/fishao/?play=jugar` I want to use `.../juegos/fishao/jugar`

Every time I load the URL with `../jugar/` or `../full/` I have an 404 error.

And this is the permalink configuration in Wordpress:
`http://www.juegoskids.com  /juegos/%postname%/`

Could you help me to fix this?

Comment: You can't do this in PHP. You must do this at the server layer, e.g. `.htaccess` rewrite rules. Keep in mind most [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) have support for this built-in, they have a routing layer to map URLs to specific actions within your code. Have a look at things like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) and [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) to see if they can help solve your problem easily.

Comment: Your rewrite rule is messed up, but this CAN be done in WP, I don't know what tadman is talking about. What is "juegos"? A custom post type? Page? Or just something prepended to the permalink?

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule doesn't make much sense because it's matching "juegos" and the %postname%, but then you're also trying to do a regex match in the rewrite. AND, all you need to do is get the query var by using `get_query_var()`. No need to parse the url.

Try this:

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "play";
    return $aVars;
}

$aNewRules = array('^juegos/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&play=$matches[2]');

$parametro = get_query_var('play');
switch ($parametro) {
    case 'jugar':
        include( get_template_directory() . '/single-play.php');
        break;
    case 'full':
        include( get_template_directory() . '/single-full.php');
        break;
}
```

(I used switch/case for cleanliness, but you can use the if/else block if you want)

Also, make sure to flush your permalinks after adding or changing a rewrite rule.